# Cloudflare doesn't block the access to my nuxt app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, cloudflare

I'm looking for a small project using **`Nuxt JS`** and i would like to use **cloudflare** for my domain, 
but i can't access  to my development platform after enabling **cloudflare**, since **cloudflare** don't allow port number **8000**,

right now to access to my **nuxt app** i have to use **`mydomain.com:8000`** is there any way to access to my website without using the port **`8000`**.
this is my config file :

```
  server: {
    port: 8000, // default: 3000
    host: '0.0.0.0' // default: localhost
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try port 80. It is a default http port, all you'll need to do is access your website without any ports like so `mydomain.com`